# how to fetching rest api data on flutter ? (on IOS & running on IOS simulator for testing)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

anyone have experience about fetching data from rest api on IOS ? should i open any permission.INTERNET same as on android ? and the URL rest api have any special ip address when we run on IOS Simulator same as Android Emulator (example: http://10.0.2.2) ? thank for advance

```
void getHttp() async {
    try {
      var response =
          await Dio().get("http://10.0.2.2:3000/find_customer/{}/{}");
      print('data : $response');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do any permision work for ios as you do for android.

And IOS simulator uses the host machine network so you should be able to just use localhost:

```
http://localhost:8000/your_path
```

Comment: What do you mean by your_path?

Comment: It means path of your app located.